# Proxie no Ionic

Tags: ionic, angular, http

Estou tendo problemas para fazer requisições http no Ionic, vi que uma forma de burlar o CORS é usando proxies.

Tentei algo como:

**ionic.config.json:**

```
{
  "name": "appIonic",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/loginnovo",
      "proxyUrl": "https://loginsiteapixx/loginnovo"
    }],
  "type": "ionic-angular"
}
```

No meu serviço:

```
basepath = "";

  constructor(public _http: HttpClient, private _platform: Platform) {

    if(this._platform.is("cordova")){
      this.basepath = "https://loginsiteapixx"
    }

  }


  public login(credenciais){
    return this._http.post(this.basepath + '/loginnovo',
    {email: credenciais.email, password: credenciais.password}, 
    {observe: 'response'}) 
    .pipe(
      map((response) => ({data: response.body, status: response.status}))
    )}
```

Quando inicio o Ionic ele me retorna que foi adicionado o proxie, mas quando realizo a requisição, o cors me barra. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Essa configuração só funciona rodando pelo `ionic serve`. Ou seja, se for rodar no aparelho (cordova) não irá funcionar.

Caso tenha controle sobre o backend, é interessante implementar o filtro de CORS no lado servidor. Caso isso não seja possível, existem 2 plugins podem te ajudar:

1. [Native/http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/): como o próprio [ionic recomenda](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#i-cant-implement-cors). Porém, só irá funcionar rodando no dispositivo.
2. Se a sua aplicação precisa que rode no browser também, ou queira utilizar o Http do Angular para as requisições, você pode utilizar [ionic-native-http-connection-backend](https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend).

Espero que ajude!